# read gridview data and output it to screen

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to read the datetime of every row and write it to the screen but I keep getting System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. There is data in the grid so I'm unsure why it doesn't find anything in column 'orderDate'.

```
        For Each r As GridViewRow in gdvOrders.Rows
            If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim orderDate As datetime
                orderDate = r.Cells(7).FindControl("orderDate").ToString 
                Dim test as string=orderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                response.write(test)
            End If
        Next r



        <asp:GridView ID="gdvSentOrders" width="100%" runat="server" style="font-size:1.5em" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No orders" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="orderID" DataSourceID="DSSentOrders" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
            <Columns>    
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("stallMessage") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="postcode" HeaderText="Postcode" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="phoneNumber" HeaderText="Phone No" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="tblNo" HeaderText="Table" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="orderDate" DataFormatString="{0: H:mm:ss}" HeaderText="Order Time" SortExpression="orderDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="timeFor" DataFormatString="{0: H:mm:ss}" HeaderText="Time For" SortExpression="timeFor" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="paid" HeaderText="Paid" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Where do you get this exception? I mean on what line?

Comment: On this line: orderDate = r.Cells(7).FindControl("orderDate").ToString